# default user.properties file to generate Jmeter HTML report from csv file?

Tags: jmeter

I'm able to generate the csv but when I click on Tools|Generate HTML report,

**user.properties file :The specified file  doesnt exist**

Isn't there some default one?

[image: jmeter error - no user .properties]

Answer (score 3):

**Default *user.properties* file comes with your JMeter installation and lives in its "bin" folder.**

If you lost your own one by accident - you can always get it back from i.e. [JMeter Github](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/bin/user.properties) or [download](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) a new JMeter build and extract it from there

The funny thing is that the "default" *user.properties* file doesn't add any value because all settings are commented out therefore you can feed an arbitrary empty file to JMeter

I think the reason for having this file is that JMeter's [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) can be customized and for example if you ran a JMeter test with one .jtl file configuration you won't be able to generate the dashboard on the "default" one, the result file configurations must match.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but if there is a default file then why does Jmeter complain if I do not provide it?

Answer (score 1):

[user.properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_gui) is required currently, you can open an enhancement for adding a default one.

> user.properties file The user.properties file used to run the load test